# Capture the browser exit event and cancel the resulting dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to capture the close of the browser and force the user to go through an exit process to save off information.

So far I have got the following javacsript, that checks whether a link or form submit have been clicked otherwise it will launch a popup.

IE has its own dialogue at this point, is there any way of stopping it showing up?

```
      var inFormOrLink;
        $('a').live('click', function () { inFormOrLink = true; });
        $('form').bind('submit', function () { inFormOrLink = true; });

        $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
            return inFormOrLink || confirmExit();
        });
```

What is best practice for handling user clicking the browser exit ('X') button?

[image]

Comment: This should not be allowed, tho

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't stop the browser from showing that pop-up and rightfully so, a website shouldn't be able to prevent the user from leaving.

Your best option is probably to make it clear to the user that they will lose information if they exit, via the message in your custom popup.